# Не работает onclick на button

Tags: html, button

Как это можно исправить?
    'Начать играть'

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Скрыть PopUp при загрузке страницы    
        PopUpHide();
    });
    //Функция отображения PopUp
    function PopUpShow(){
        $("#popup").show();
    }
    //Функция скрытия PopUp
    function PopUpHide(){
        $("#popup").hide();
    }
```

```html
<button class="play" type="submit" onsubmit="javascript:PopUpShow();">Начать играть</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Скрыть PopUp при загрузке страницы    
    PopUpHide();
});
//Функция отображения PopUp
function PopUpShow(){
    $("#popup").show();
}
//Функция скрытия PopUp
function PopUpHide(){
    $("#popup").hide();
}
```

Comment: В вопросе нет onclick, поэтому и не работает.

Comment: Не работает даже с онкликом)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте вашей кнопке идентификатор `popup` и раз уж Вам нужно событие `onclick` то и используйте его

```html
<button class="play" id="popup" type="button" onclick="PopUpShow();">Начать играть</button>
```

Comment: первое - нет, второе - да

Comment: То что там стоит onsubmit это мои уже попытки всё поправить)

Comment: Итог: кнопка не работает с идентификатором и онкликом. jquery подключен

Comment: При перемещении окна вниз кода, оно появляется сразу при загрузки страницы. Все признаки того что jquery не работает, но ошибок в консоли нету

Comment: К слову заметил, что на маленьких экранах показ работает

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `<button>` лучше всего использовать обычную ссылку `<a href="javascript:PopUpShow();">Начать играть</a>`

Comment: Не работает, в консоли ошибок нету.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Всё из-за того что у меня на фоне блока стояло видео, с `position: absolute`.

Решение:
Поставить блоку с `popup` `z-index`, чтобы перекрывал видео.